# Rundeck ui not visible after successful installation of new rundeck

Tags: java, user-interface, server, frontend, rundeck

I had installed a new version of rundeck in cloud server but i am not able to open rundeck ui. And everything is fine in backend as services are started but only issue is ui which is not getting after many trys....any suggestion how to make it visible?

Comment: More context is needed, what is your cloud provider? network config? could you share your rundeck-config.properties?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the external URL in the `grails.serverURL` parameter (on the `rundeck-config.properties` file, usually at `/etc/rundeck` path), e.g: `grails.serverURL=http://my_external_url:4440` then, restart the rundeck service. More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/install-centos.html#basic-rundeck-configuration).